# Create library based on cmake in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

I'm new to C++ and can't create dynamic link library based on CMake in QTCreator. But when I created it library based on QMake. Works with QT Creator 3.5.1.

[New File or Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNYyH.png)

[Introduction and Project Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4fHH.png)

[Kit Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3JKa.png)

[Select Required Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx59Y.png)

[Class Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoXA5.png)

[Project Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73O3q.png)

Comment: Where is your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Why are you using Qt Creator 3.5? The latest version is 4.8 and Qt5. I would suggest to give a read here on creating a cmake project with Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: @drescherjm When I created library only connection.pro file generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qtcreator can only read the structure of an existing CMakeLists.txt (and it does a good job at that), but it cannot create or edit it for you. If you don't have a CMakeLists.txt yet, you want to create a new one and then open it in Qtcreator with "File->Open File or Project". If you already have a CMakeLists.txt, you want to edit it adding a new `add_library` command and then Qtcreator should pick up the change automatically or maybe after you do "Build->Run CMake".

On another note, you should if possible follow the advice from the comments and install a later version of Qtcreator via the official installer.